# Take unique value to consider only second column in shell

Tags: shell

I have a file which contain below data. I want to take unique data to consider only second column.

```
May 23, 2013|380565195-00001
May 23, 2013|386277814-00001
May 15, 2013|370674334-00001
May 23, 2013|370674334-00001
May 23, 2013|422011458-00001
May 21, 2013|620734890-00001
May 23, 2013|721962541-00001
May 22, 2013|820591328-00001
May 23, 2013|820591328-00001
May 10, 2013|900544559-00099
May 23, 2013|900544559-00099
May 23, 2013|981242670-00001
```

Output should be like below.

```
May 23, 2013|380565195-00001
May 23, 2013|386277814-00001
May 15, 2013|370674334-00001    
May 23, 2013|422011458-00001
May 21, 2013|620734890-00001
May 23, 2013|721962541-00001
May 22, 2013|820591328-00001
May 10, 2013|900544559-00099
May 23, 2013|981242670-00001
```

Please help me on this.

Comment: please give a better description. "unique data to consider" is totally vague

Comment: @KarolyHorvath OP wants to remove from the input list entries which have same second column data. So each entry in the output list should be unique for its second column content.

Comment: I guess it does matter which one do you remove, doesn't it? And yes, I can see the example, but the description is still ridiculous.

Comment: Do you need to keep original order?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
awk -F"|"  '{if (!h[$2]) {h[$2]=1; print;}}'
```